# getting user facebook info in as3 air mobile app

Tags: android, facebook, actionscript-3, air, user-data

I an developing a mobile app that loges in using Facebook username and pass. i am having runtime errors when trying to retrieve user details. I am using the as3 Facebook api.

```
ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on Classes::WebViewLogin/userData(). Expected 0, got 2.
```

here is my code

```
public function callInit (){
        FacebookMobile.init(APP_ID, onInit);
    }

    public function onInit(success:Object, fail:Object):void{
        if (success){ 
            trace("Already logged in");
        }
        else{
            trace("Not logged in");
            addChild(logInBtn);
            logInBtn.x = logInBtn.y =200;
            logInBtn.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, logInbtnPressed);
        }
    }

    private function logInbtnPressed(e:TouchEvent){
        trace("-----------log in btn pressed-----------");
        removeChild(logInBtn);

        webView.stage = stage;
        webView.viewPort = new Rectangle(10, 10, (stage.stageWidth -15), (stage.stageHeight - 15));
        FacebookMobile.login( onLogin , this.stage, extendedPermissions, webView);
    }

    public function onLogin(success:Object, fail:Object):void{
        trace ("onLogin function called");
        if (success){
            trace("Logged In\n");
            //accessCamera.loggedIn();

            getUserData();

            addChild(logOutBtn);
            logOutBtn.x = logInBtn.y =200;
            logOutBtn.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, onLogout);
        }
        else{
            trace("Login Failed\n");
            logInErr.text = "Error logging in to Facebook";
            addChild(logInErr);
            logInErr.border = true;

            addChild(logInBtn);
            logInBtn.x = logInBtn.y =200;
            logInBtn.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, logInbtnPressed);
        }
    }

    public function getUserData(){
                    //-----------possible suspect line---------------//
        FacebookMobile.api("/me" , userData);
    }

    public function userData(){
        trace ("userdata method");
    }

    public function onLogout(success:Boolean):void {
        removeChild(logOutBtn);
        trace("Log out");
    }

    private function logOutbtnPressed(){
        FacebookMobile.logout();
    }
```

I am new to working with facebook and mobile apps and can find very little help with using this api. any help would be greatly appreciated.

**edit** any help on the problem i am having rather than alternative methods?

Answer (score 1):

If you need something quickly you can buy GoViral from Milkman http://www.milkmangames.com/blog/tools/, they will provide Tutorials and email support for about $50

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a better way will be to use the FreshPlanet ANE here :
https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-Facebook

It's write especially for mobile so you can use direct connect from the device

Comment: what is the documentation like or are there m/any tutorials on it. i am already behind on this project. I also have never used an ane

Comment: I found this link, sample for the AirFacebook of fresh planet =>[https://github.com/jefflim/facebook.connect.sample/blob/master/src/FacebookConnect.as](https://github.com/jefflim/facebook.connect.sample/blob/master/src/FacebookConnect.as)